# JavaScript iterate through 2D array and return the mismatches

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

I have two 2D arrays, I want to compare them using JavaScript, ignore the matches and if there are mismatches to return the entire row into a new array.

```
    var array1 = [ ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'],
                 ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'],
                 ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'],
                 ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'],
                 [null,'ABC'],
                 ['6f93cfa0106f','xxx'],
                  ];

    var array2 = [ ['52a1fd0296fc','ABC'],
                   ['6f93cfa0106f','xxx'],
                   ['52a1fd0296fc','ABC'],
                   ['52a1fd0296fc','ABC'],
                   ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'],
                   ['52a1fd0296fcasd','DEF'],  ];
```

I want to take this output, the arrays that exists in array2 and NOT in array1:

```
array3 = [['52a1fd0296fcasd','DEF'],['52a1fd0296fc','ABC']]
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Whats the expected output?

Comment: what means ***mismatch***?

Comment: The expected output is a new 2D array with the unique values. 
array3 = [ [null, 'ABC'] ]

Comment: I want to check this statement:
if (array1[0] === array2[0] && if array1[1] === array2[1])

Comment: What unique values? "52a1fd0296fc" ? or "ABC" ? Or unique arrays? Please be clear and tell us exactly what output you expect.

Comment: I want this kind of output for example : array3 = [ [null, 'ABC'],  ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF']]. According to your answer I want the unique arrays.

Comment: why the changed order in the result array?

Comment: It doesn't matter the order, we care only about the existence of these values

Comment: then you may have a look to my answer, where the order is taken from `array2`.

Comment: Really thanks for your contribution..I will try to understand it first

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over both arrays:

```js
var array1 = [ ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'],
                 ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'],
                 ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'],
                 ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'],
                 [null,'ABC'],
                 ['6f93cfa0106f','xxx'],
                 ['52a1fd0296fc','ABC'] ];

var array2 = [ ['52a1fd0296fc','ABC'],
                   ['6f93cfa0106f','xxx'],
                   ['52a1fd0296fc','ABC'],
                   ['52a1fd0296fc','ABC'],
                   ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'] ];
                   
var array3 = [];
for(var i = 0; i<array1.length; ++i) {
 var a = array1[i];
 var found = false;
 for(var j = 0; j<array2.length; ++j) {
  var b = array2[j];
  if(a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1]) {
   found = true;
   break;
  }
 }
 if(!found) {
  array3.push(a);
 }
}

console.dir(array3);
```

I assume you want array1 without array2 and not the other way around.

Comment: It works, but the `Array.find` method is more elegant than writing a loop with a `found=true` boolean.

Comment: According to Mozilla specs at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find, `Array.find` is not compatible with IE and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the joined values of the array as key and filter the once of the second array, while indicating already inserted items.

```js
var array1 = [ ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'], ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'], ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'], ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'], [null,'ABC'], ['6f93cfa0106f','xxx']],
    array2 = [ ['52a1fd0296fc','ABC'], ['6f93cfa0106f','xxx'], ['52a1fd0296fc','ABC'], ['52a1fd0296fc','ABC'], ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'], ['52a1fd0296fcasd','DEF']],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result;

array1.forEach(function (a) {
     hash[a.join('|')] = true;
});

result = array2.filter(function (a) {
    return !hash[a.join('|')] && (hash[a.join('|')] = true);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Running this just outputs `[
  [
    null,
    "ABC"
  ]
]`, that's not the expected output. OP wants to deduplicate the main array

Comment: it is exactly the result of the first comments answer of op.

Comment: You're right, but OP was very unclear then, check out their last comment.

Comment: @JeremyThille, i see no rule in the last answer. is there any?

Comment: OP said : `I want this kind of output for example : array3 = [ [null, 'ABC'], ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF']]. I want the unique arrays.`

Comment: @JeremyThille, i read this, but what is unique with this result/s?

Comment: What do you mean? OP just want to deduplicate the arrays, that's it. They just don't want duplicates.

Comment: Also something else, I want to check if arrays of array2 are exists in the array1. And if not exist to store them in a new array.

Comment: @AlexBotzis, please **add some use cases**.

Comment: The array2 is extracted from an object, the array1 is outcome from SQL DB, so this I want to achieve is to make somehow the combination of two elements in each row in array1 a 'unique key' (['52a1fd0296fc','DEF']). So if in array2 exists an array that is ALSO in array1, I want to reject it. I only want to store those arrays that are in array2 and NOT in array1.

Comment: @AlexBotzis, if so, you get an empty array. please add some examples to the question. in the structure: input, output/outcome and what leads to to the exact output. for example you have two sets and you dfine which parts of the set i used for comparison and the you take a subset of the two sets, then you could write it. actually it's maneuvering in the dark.

Comment: I edited my example.Hope it helps to understand what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Here's my go at it, maybe more compact (and using ES6)

This code removes duplicate arrays from the main array.

```js
var array1 = [ ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'],
                 ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'],
                 ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'],
                 ['52a1fd0296fc','DEF'],
                 [null,'ABC'],
                 ['6f93cfa0106f','xxx'],
                 ['52a1fd0296fc','ABC'] ];

let array3 = []

array1.forEach( a1 => {
 if(!array3.find(a2 => a2[0]===a1[0] && a2[1]===a1[1])) array3.push(a1)
})

console.log(array3)
```