# How do I delete empty columns with the header in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below code which helps me delete all the empty columns in the right end. But I also have empty columns in between the sheet, and all these empty columns are with headers.

I want to delete empty columns with header, can somebody please assist me in this.

```
function removeEmptyColumns() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
   for (var s in allsheets){
      var sheet=allsheets[s]
      var maxColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns(); 
      var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
      if (maxColumns-lastColumn != 1){
         sheet.deleteColumns(lastColumn+2, maxColumns-lastColumn);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: do loop from last column until first column, find non empty cell from lastrow up, if you find the row as your header row or the row is 1, so you delete the column

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'm not a geek, and I would appreciate if you could provide me the code.

Comment: Would you please share your sheet?

Comment: I give you sample, please look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here the sample as your request

```
function UntitledMacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  Logger.log("1");
   var allsheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
   //In this sample I just to check 1 sheet only
   //so temporarily the for loop is commented, and column header is in row 1
   //and will delete all header without data and all column without header
   for (var sht in allsheets){
      var sheet=spreadsheet.getSheetByName(allsheets[shtNo].getSheetName());
      Logger.log("2");
      var maxColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns(); 
      var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
      if (maxColumns-lastColumn != 0){
         if (maxColumns>lastColumn)
         {
           Logger.log("3");
           sheet.deleteColumns(lastColumn+1, maxColumns-lastColumn);
         }
         for (a=0; a<lastColumn; a++)
         {
           var lstRange1 = sheet.getRange(1,lastColumn - a );
           if (lstRange1.getValue()=='') 
           {
             sheet.deleteColumns(lastColumn - a +1);
           }
           else
           {
             var lstRange2= sheet.getRange(lastrow, lastColumn - a );
             if (lstRange2.getValue()=='')
             {
               var rsltRange=lstRange2.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP);
               if (rsltRange.getRow()==1) sheet.deleteColumns(lastColumn - a +1,1);
             }
           }
         } 

      }

   }
};
```

Update:

```
function UntitledMacro3() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var allsheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();

   for (var shtNo in allsheets){
      var sheet=spreadsheet.getSheetByName(allsheets[shtNo].getSheetName());
      var maxColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns(); 
      var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
      if (maxColumns-lastColumn != 0){
         if (maxColumns>lastColumn)
         {
           sheet.deleteColumns(lastColumn+1, maxColumns-lastColumn);
         }
      }
      if (lastColumn>0)
      {
         for (a=0; a<lastColumn; a++)
         {
          var lstRange1 = sheet.getRange(1,lastColumn - a );
           if (lstRange1.getValue()=='') 
           {
             sheet.deleteColumns(lastColumn - a );
           }
           else
           {
             var lstRange2= sheet.getRange(lastrow, lastColumn - a );
             if (lstRange2.getValue()=='')
             {
               var rsltRange=lstRange2.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP);
               if (rsltRange.getRow()==1 && (lastColumn - a )<=maxColumns) sheet.deleteColumns(lastColumn - a ,1);
             }
           }
         } 

      }

   }
};
```

Now for all sheet. Run the script, then after finish, please key press Ctrl+Enter, to show the log, please inform the log content

pict before:

[image]

pict After:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, however the code isn't doing anything in my sheet, it doesn't give any error either. Does it have anything to do with
Logger.log("dfsdfsdf");?

Comment: Logger.log("dfsdfsdf") only for checking the run of script, it can be ommited

Comment: And you must check your sheet name to replace sheet2 in my script. And please check the log after run, if dfsdfsdf shown, so the script run well

Comment: The result is still the same, I'm executing this in "Sheet2". But still nothings really happening..

Comment: try with all sheet, I will modify my script

Comment: I pasted your updated code, I received the below error
TypeError: sheet.getMaxColumns is not a function
UntitledMacro @ Code.gs:11
In line 11

Comment: deleteColumns have been deprecated now

Comment: Although it has deprecated, I update the script, and the script still can run until now, please look at my update

Comment: This worked well with few minor changes.. Thank you so much for your assistance..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to iterate over your Sheets, looking for written values in each Column, avoiding the header Row. The script could have this logic:

1. Get all the data of each Sheet with [getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) and [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getValues()). This will generate a 2D array, which is logically represented as a matrix:

[image]

2. Make two `for` loops to [iterate through the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516492/) generated in Step 1.
3. [Make a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50104776/trying-to-check-the-value-of-a-cell-and-compare-it-to-another-value-to-see-if-it) to check if there is any cell with a value different than `""`, if so, don't delete the Column.

I also suggest you to make the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/apps-script) to learn the basics of Spreadsheets and Apps Script.