# How to delete empty columns with header in google sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Someone asked this before but not working [How do I delete empty columns with the header in google sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59676029/18435651) I still have issues that it shows cannot delete the column but only can hide. How to make the code work?

Comment: I think that [the script (`Update:`) in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59690982/7108653) works. So can I ask you about your current issue of `Someone asked this before but not working How do I delete empty columns with the header in google sheet? I still have issues that it shows cannot delete the column but only can hide. How to make the code work?`?

Comment: @Tanike, it doesn't delete the columns well, some columns are not deteled after I run the scripts. Couldn't find the error from it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `some columns are not deteled`, I cannot imagine such columns. In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide the sample input and output you expect as the image? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 2):

#### Delete All Empty Columns

```
function deleteAllEmptyColumns() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const cols = sh.getLastColumn();
  let d = 0;
  [...Array.from(new Array(cols).keys())].forEach((idx => {
    if (sh.getRange(1, idx + 1 - d, sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().filter(e => e).length == 0) {
      sh.deleteColumn(idx + 1 - d++);//delete counter increments here
    }
  }));
  sh.deleteColumns(sh.getLastColumn() + 1, sh.getMaxColumns() - sh.getLastColumn());

}
```

You must remember to keep track of the columns deleted to the left of getLastColumn().

Answer (score 0):

@Cooper's the prefered solution.

I just found this other Filtering with Query formula method from [this source](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/filter-out-blank-columns-in-google-sheets-using-query-formula/#:%7E:text=Filter%20Out%20Blank%20Columns%20in%20Google%20Sheets%20Using%20Query%20Formula,-By&text=Instead%20of%20manually%20making%20the,the%20functions%20Filter%20or%20Query.) that might help for result but without headers in blank columns:

```
= ArrayFormula(Query(transpose(Query(TRANSPOSE({
    Query({
        Sheet1!A1:MJ1;to_text(Query({
            if(Sheet1!A2:MJ<>"", 1, 0)
        }, "Select "&JOIN(",","Sum(Col"&column(Sheet1!A1:MJ1)&")")))
    },"Offset 1",1);
    Sheet1!A2:MJ
}), "Select * Where Col2<>'0'",1)),"Select * Offset 1", 1))
```